# Flash / FLV - How do I extract MetaData from an FLV?

Tags: flash, flv, streaming-flv-video

What software is available for extracting metadata from an FLV? I'm testing an flv streaming module for apache (mod_flvx) and need to extract keyframe info from an flv for debugging purposes.

I was only able to find FLV MetaData Viewer, but its dated, from 2006, and doesn't install properly on Win7. http://www.buraks.com/flvmdv/

**Edit:** I'm open to any method of extraction, either app or library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about tools, but maybe you can use **ffmpeg** as reference.

You must parse flv to find metadata chunk. It's not hard.

Then look at `flv_read_metabody` function from **libavformat\flvdec.c**. Metadata in flv is simply an [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) object.

But if keyframe info is only you need, you can don't touch metadata at all. You can parse flv: each video chunk marked if it's a kayframe.

---

**Update:**

You can use **[FLVTool2](http://www.inlet-media.de/flvtool2/)** to extract MetaData.